# Fabric SDK unable to initialize cryptosuite config

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric

I'm running a business network on IBM Cloud Blockchain Platform 2.0. I downloaded a connection profile from the instantiated smart contracts section on the Platform Console, and am trying to connect using the Fabric SDK for Go but I am facing an error.

This is my current relevant code, under main

```
configOpts := fabricConfig.FromFile("./profiles/flex.json")
fabSDK, err := fabsdk.New(configOpts)
if err != nil {
    entry.WithError(err).Fatal("Error setting up Fabric SDK")
}
defer fabSDK.Close()
```

Expected: Connects to the business network instance

Actual: I get an error

```
FATA[0000] Error setting up Fabric SDK env=DEV 
error="failed to initialize configuration: unable to initialize cryptosuite using crypto suite config: 
failed to initialize crypto suite: Unsupported BCCSP Provider: "
```

Answer (score 0):

I add "cryptoconfig" path to the client.

BCCSP is optional, and you can remove.

I added the sample config, please see below.

More detail config at Github go-SDK [config.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/master/pkg/core/config/testdata/template/config.yaml)

```
{
"name": "first-network-org1",
"version": "1.0.0",
"client": {
    "organization": "Org1",
    "logging": {
        "level": "info"
    },
    "cryptoconfig": {
        "path": "crypto-config"
    },
    "credentialStore": {
        "path": "/tmp/keystore",
        "cryptoStore": {
            "path": "/tmp/msp"
        }
    },
    "connection": {
        "timeout": {
            "peer": {
                "endorser": "300"
            }
        }
    }
},
"channels": {
    "mychannel": {
        "peers": {
            "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
        }
    }
},
"orderers": {
    "orderer.example.com": {
        "url": "orderer.example.com:7050",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer.example.com",
            "keep-alive-time": "60s",
            "keep-alive-timeout": "60s",
            "keep-alive-permit": false,
            "fail-fast": false,
            "allow-insecure": false
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem"
        }
    }
},
"organizations": {
    "Org1": {
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "cryptoPath": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp",
        "peers": [
            "peer0.org1.example.com",
            "peer1.org1.example.com"
        ],
        "certificateAuthorities": [
            "ca.org1.example.com"
        ]
    }
},
"peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
        },
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
        }
    },
    "peer1.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:8051",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
        },
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org1.example.com"
        }
    }
},
"certificateAuthorities": {
    "ca.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "https://localhost:7054",
        "caName": "ca-org1",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
        },
        "httpOptions": {
            "verify": false
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: IBM blockchain platform doesn’t give the crypto config files you get if you deploy the network yourself, that’s why it’s a problem

Comment: I agree with you. I workaround to much to solved config files. And now I try too hard with GO SDK. I can't run go test from Github and I don't know why.